# Should I move a callee's return value if I'm going to construct an object with it?

Tags: c++, c++11, return-value, move, move-semantics

```
class Item { };

class Wrapper
{
    Item i;
    Wrapper(const Item& mI) : i{mI} { }
    Wrapper(Item&& mI) : i{std::move(mI)} { }
};

Item createItem()
{
    Item result;
    // ...
    return result; // No `std::move` needed here
}

Wrapper createWrapper()
{
    Wrapper result{createItem()}; // `std::move(createItem())` ?
    return result;
}
```

`createItem()` returns efficiently without having to call `std::move`.

`createWrapper()` uses the return value of `createItem()` and wants to call the `Wrapper::Wrapper(Item&&)` constructor.

Is it necessary to to use `Wrapper result{std::move(createItem())};` or will `Wrapper result{createItem()};` suffice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no need for `std::move` here. The value of a function call expression is already an *rvalue*.

Comment: Is it a prvalue as well?

Comment: @0x499602D2: Yes, but that's not relevant to this question.

Answer (score 0):

`std::move` is **not** required for returning objects:

```
BigMatrix BuildBigMatrix()
{
   ...
   return someBigMatrix; // *moved* outside of function
}
```